# HttpPost a list of items in Swagger

Tags: c#, swagger

I have a model class like so -

```
public class Request
{
   public List<ProductIDs> ProductIDs { get; set; }
   public string Pid { get; set; }

}
```

In Swagger, it shows up like this -

[image]

In the picture, I am sending a value of `32a`, but I am suppose to send `"32a"` or something. My issue is that when I make a request, the `pid` gets to the controller. But `ProductIDs` is always 0.

Comment: Can you post the code of your POST method and the `ProductIDs` class, so that others can reproduce your problem more easily?

Comment: @Helen Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are passing down an object "ProductID" instead of a string. If your ProductID class only has one variable, a string, it might just be simpler to use:

```
public List<string> ProductIDs { get; set; }
```

Otherwise if ProductID has multiple variables such as ID, Location, Amount etc. you will need to pass down an object instead of a string. Meaning it will look something like this in the actual swagger entry:

```
{"ID": "32a", "var2": 421112, "Product Available":false}
```

Swagger can read that as an object and assign the correct fields. If you just pass down a number or letter like 32a it essentially reads it as an empty or incorrectly formed object.

Comment: Tried passing in `{"ProductID": "32a"}` since `ProductID` class just has one variable but it still didn't work.